# How to toggle a div in correct time and day of the week

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to know how to toggle a div on correct time and week days. Example:- when sunday 12:00pm div1 will show, in monday 12:00 div2 will show others time stay hidden. This code works fine hide show on correct time but i also want to add Week days to show hide like  `if (day== sunday || n > '08:59' && n < '09:59'){}`

```
        function running() {
        Object.prototype.twoDigits = function () {
            return ("0" + this).slice(-2);
        }

        // get current date and time
        let now = new Date();
        n = now.getHours().twoDigits() + ':' + now.getMinutes().twoDigits();

        if (n > '08:59' && n < '09:59') {
            $(".class-1").addClass("now").removeClass("old");
            $('.class-1 .overlay').hide();
            $('.class-2 .overlay').show();
            $('.class-3 .overlay').show();
            $('.class-4 .overlay').show();
            $('.class-1 .overlay-2').hide();
            $('.class-2 .overlay-2').hide();
            $('.class-3 .overlay-2').hide();
            $('.class-4 .overlay-2').hide();
        }
        else if (n > '09:59' && n < '10:59') {
            $(".class-2").addClass("now").removeClass("old");
            $('.class-1 .overlay').hide();
            $('.class-2 .overlay').hide();
            $('.class-3 .overlay').show();
            $('.class-4 .overlay').show();
            $('.class-1 .overlay-2').show();
            $('.class-2 .overlay-2').hide();
            $('.class-3 .overlay-2').hide();
            $('.class-4 .overlay-2').hide();
           
        }
        else if (n > '10:59' && n < '11:29') {
            
            $('.class-1 .overlay').hide();
            $('.class-2 .overlay').hide();
            $('.class-3 .overlay').show();
            $('.class-4 .overlay').show();
            $('.class-1 .overlay-2').show();
            $('.class-2 .overlay-2').show();
            $('.class-3 .overlay-2').hide();
            $('.class-4 .overlay-2').hide();
           
        }   
       
        else {
            $(".class-1").addClass("old").removeClass("now");
            $(".class-2").addClass("old").removeClass("now");
            $(".class-3").addClass("old").removeClass("now");
            $(".class-4").addClass("old").removeClass("now");
            $('.hooray').show();
            $('.overlay').show();
            $('.overlay-2').hide();
          
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        running();
    });
```

Comment: and what is your question ? find current week day ?

Comment: I want to add week day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `const d = now.getDay()` which returns 0 - 6 where 0 = Sunday. Then you can chech for specific day in your if statements like `if(d === 3 && … )` to check wednesday.

Comment: if (d === 0 && d === 2 && d === 4 || n > '09:00' && n < '09:59') {} will it work?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by this - when do you need this statement to be true?

Comment: I want to make a online class routine. When correct time zoom links will show others time hideen

Comment: Showing links in particulsr time only on specific days can be achieved like this: `if ((d === 0 || d === 2 || d === 4) && (n > '09:00' && n < '09:59'))`